# How to compile multiple C source File to Object File using Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is the makefile code and I execute it using "make".

```makefile
CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc
CXX = arm-none-eabi-g++
BUILD_PATH = ../../build
dir_guard=mkdir -p $(@D)
STATIC_OPENTHREAD_LIB = $(BUILD_PATH)/third_party/libopenthread.a
AR = arm-none-eabi-gcc-ar -cr 

TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH = openthread


NRF_802154_MODULE_NAME = nrf_802154
NRF_802154_MODULE_PATH ?= $(PROJECT_ROOT)/third_party/$(NRF_802154_MODULE_NAME)

TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH = $(NRF_802154_MODULE_PATH)



INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/include/
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/rsch/raal/softdevice 
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/rsch/raal
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/hal
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/nrfx/mdk
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/nrfx
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/dependencies
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/include/openthread
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/include/openthread/platform
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src/fem
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src/hal
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src/mac_features
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src/platform/clock
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src/platform/temperature
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src/platform/timer
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src/raal
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src/raal/softdevice
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_NRF_802154_PATH)/nrf_802154/src/timer_scheduler
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/examples/platforms
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/include/openthread
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/clock
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/nrfx/hal
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/nrfx/drivers/include
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/libraries/app_error
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/src/core
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/cmsis
INCLUDE_DIRS := openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/nrfx/mdk/

CFLAGS += -DENABLE_DEBUG_LOG=1 -DENABLE_DEBUG_GPIO=0 -DENABLE_DEBUG_ASSERT=0  
CFLAGS += -DSTM32_DEVICE -DnRF52840 -DNRF52840_XXAA -DPLATFORM_THREADING=1 -DPLATFORM_ID=14 -DPLATFORM_NAME=xenon -DUSBD_VID_SPARK=0x2B04 -DUSBD_PID_DFU=0xD00E -DUSBD_PID_CDC=0xC00E -g3 -gdwarf-2 -Os -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -DSOFTDEVICE_PRESENT=1 -DS140 -DINCLUDE_PLATFORM=1 -DOPENTHREAD_PROJECT_CORE_CONFIG_FILE=\"openthread-config-project.h\" -DENABLE_FEM=1 -DNRF_802154_PROJECT_CONFIG=\"openthread-platform-config.h\" -DRAAL_SOFTDEVICE=1 -D_WIZCHIP_=W5500 -fno-builtin -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -DDFU_BUILD_ENABLE -DLFS_CONFIG=lfs_config.h -DSYSTEM_VERSION_STRING=0.8.0-rc.27 -DRELEASE_BUILD 

CFLAGS += -DENABLE_FEM=1 -Werror
CFLAGS += -DNRF_802154_PROJECT_CONFIG=\"openthread-platform-config.h\"
CFLAGS += -DRAAL_SOFTDEVICE=1
CFLAGS += -DNRF52840_AAAA=0 -DNRF52840_AABA=0

CFLAGS += -DNRF52840_AAAA=0 -DNRF52840_AABA=0
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_notification_swi.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_priority_drop_swi.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_request_swi.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_swi.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/rsch/raal/softdevice/nrf_raal_softdevice.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_ack_pending_bit.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_core.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_core_hooks.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_critical_section.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_debug.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_pib.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_revision.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/rsch/nrf_802154_rsch.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_rssi.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_rx_buffer.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_timer_coord.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/fem/nrf_fem_control.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/mac_features/nrf_802154_precise_ack_timeout.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/mac_features/nrf_802154_csma_ca.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/mac_features/nrf_802154_delayed_trx.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/mac_features/nrf_802154_filter.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/platform/clock/nrf_802154_clock_sdk.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/platform/hp_timer/nrf_802154_hp_timer.c
CSRC += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/timer_scheduler/nrf_802154_timer_sched.c

ALLOBJ := $(addprefix $(BUILD_PATH)/, $(CSRC:.c=.o))

all:$(ALLOBJ)

%.o: %.c
    echo $^

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_PATH)
```

But it fails with this error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '../../build/openthread/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio/nrf_802154_notification_swi.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop
```

It seems like it does not recognize the pattern.

The % pattern has to recognize the rule being called but its not working

What I want to do is my source code is in different directory and I want build a makefile that can compile C and create objects in different directory and then want to create .a library using AR.

Comment: Looks to me like all of your `INCLUDE_DIRS` statements are wrong. They use `:=` instead of `+=`.

Comment: difference between := and += ? in short

Comment: The second is additive (it adds to the previous). The first replaces (the sec Inond replaces the first, meaning the first is lost). See the use in `CSRC` in your own post. In code, `a = 1; a = 2` means `a == 2`, while `a = 1; a += 1;` means `a == 3`.

Comment: and meaning of :=

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern rule can't match, because you are matching the whole path names on both sides. But your path prefixes aren't the same, e.g.

- source file `$(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/...`
- object file `../../build/$(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/...`

The simple fix would be:

```makefile
ALLOBJ := $(addprefix $(BUILD_PATH)/, $(CSRC:.c=.o))

$(ALLOBJ): $(BUILD_PATH)/%.o: %.c
        .... compiler command line goes in here ....
```

But a much simpler approach would be to use [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Directory-Search) instead, i.e. tell make where to look for the source files and remove the paths from the source files altogether:

```makefile
# location of the source files (you can have multiple source directories too)
VPATH += $(TARGET_OPENTHREAD_SRC_PATH)/third_party/NordicSemiconductor/drivers/radio

CSRC += nrf_802154_notification_swi.c

ALLOBJ := $(addprefix $(BUILD_PATH)/, $(CSRC:.c=.o))

$(ALLOBJ): $(BUILD_PATH)/%.o: %.c
        .... compiler command line goes in here ....
```

Comment: Sir but the problem is my source codes are in different directories i have to specify all the different directory and .c file isn't it too lengthy task? because i have to match the source code file to that path

Comment: As I mentioned, you can assign multiple directories to `VPATH`. A second option is to assign the source root directory to `VPATH` and strip the root part from the source file names. And while you are at it: you can use the same list of directories to generate the `-I` list for the `CFLAGS`.

Comment: oh that's mean i don't have to put absolute path for the source file right all i have to do it . assign a root directory of the source code and it will find the source file which is mentioned right ?

Comment: Exactly. I would suggest to read the section of the GNU make manual I have linked to in my answer.